# how to decode \xe2\x80\xa6 in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, decode, non-ascii-characters

For my text mining assignment, I need to preprocessing my data(tweet) in python from twitter before I put it into word vector, but the tweet that I got from crawling data on twitter has a non-ASCII character.
How to decode it to the real text?

for example:
'halo kak vicki, anti cek saat ini permintaan buka isolirnya sudah dilakukan ya. apakah jaringan indihome\xe2\x80\xa6'

this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import re
import ast
import nltk
from Sastrawi.StopWordRemover.StopWordRemoverFactory import StopWordRemoverFactory
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

training = pd.read_csv('indihome2.csv')
column = training["tweet"]
uname = column.str.replace(r'@[A-Za-z0-9]+', '')
html = uname.str.replace('https://', '')
tco = html.str.replace('t.co/[a-zA-z0-9]+', '')
forb = tco.str.lstrip(':b')
fornonascii = forb.encode('latin1').decode('unicode_escape')
```

i already trying encode('latin1').decode('unicode_escape') but it getting error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: `'\xe2\x80\xa6'` is a Unicode for `'…'`. Have you tried setting the encoding? `pd.read_csv('indihome2.csv', encoding="utf8")`.

Comment: i try it but nothing happen

Comment: Have you looked into the `unidecode` package?

Comment: i installed it and i think it still the same. But i guess the problem is from the tweepy.API, i should add "tweet_mode=extended" on the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
raw_str = b'\xe2\x80\xa6'
str(raw_str, 'utf-8')

# Prints "-" 


raw_str = b'halo kak vicki, anti cek saat ini permintaan buka isolirnya sudah dilakukan ya. apakah jaringan indihome\xe2\x80\xa6'
str(raw_str, 'utf-8')

# Prints 'halo kak vicki, anti cek saat ini permintaan buka isolirnya sudah dilakukan ya. apakah jaringan indihome…'
```

Comment: how to do it for a whole file?